# how should i include additional assemblies (COM, Dlls) etc

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, clickonce

I have several additional COM objects, dlls, xls, xmls and some other types of files. some extra folders which should be on the same level where executable is.

How can include them as part of necessary files?

If I put them as data files, they go to different folders then the path becomes a problem and COM objects etc should be in the same folder as executable as they are a dependency of third-party assemblies i am using.

Comment: Please specify a type of installer you're using. ClickOnce and Windows Installer are two different types.

Comment: clickonce installer

Comment: If you really need to install other things, a bootstrapper might be necessary, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/clickonce-deployment-for-visual-cpp-applications?view=vs-2017

Comment: What kind of product is this? An Office addin? COM objects generally need to be installed per-machine and ClickOnce does not do that unless you use registration-less COM that does not work in all cases. Please show a file list and add some more details.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to just go to solution explorer -> My project -> then click on references and resources?